# login form submit in jquery post with url

Tags: jquery, forms, url, form-submit

HTML[image]

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Notification Error -->
        <div action="" id="form-error" class="d-none">
            <p>✖ Username không tồn tại</p> 
            <p>✖ Password không hợp lệ</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Login Form -->
        <form action="" id="form-login">
            <h1 class="form-heading">Login Form</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
                <i class="far fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" id="username" class="form-input" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <p class="error-Username"></p>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-input" placeholder="Password">
                <div id="eye">
                    <i class="far fa-eye-slash"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="error-Password"></p>
 
            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" class="form-submit">
            <div class="sigup-link">
                not a member? <a href="#">Sigup</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var urlLogin;

    urlLogin = "http://apiforlearning.zendvn.com/api/check-login";

    $("#form-login").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var userName = $("#username").val();

        var passWord = $("#password").val();
       
        $.post(urlLogin, function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
                if(data.type == "error"){        
                    $("#form-error").removeClass('d-none');
                } 
                
        },'json');
    });
});
```

Is there something wrong with my error box? , my problem is how can i successfully login with the above link , and when the login is successful the background login form will change to "Welcome!! LOGIN Successfully!!"

Comment: You need a else in your $post conditions.

Comment: What does it mean, can you suggest? I should put more conditions if != / something /  => success ???

Comment: Here you only do something when there is an error but nothing when it is successful. `if(data.type == "error"){ //error } else { //no error }`

Comment: It looks like you are getting an error from the API you are calling. You need to look at that error to determine what is wrong with your login request.